# how do you create highcharts bar chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to build a bar chart using highcharts. This is my function:

```
function monthly_web_login() {

        $.getJSON('monthly_web_login.php', function(data) {

        var chart = new highcharts({
         chart: {
                borderColor: '#98AFC7',
                borderRadius: 20,
                borderWidth: 1,
                renderTo: 'login',
                type: 'bar',
                marginRight: 10,

            },

            exporting: {
            enabled: true
        },
            rangeSelector: {
                enabled:false              
            },

            scrollbar: {
                    enabled: false
                    },
            navigator : {
                enabled : false
            },
            xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            tickInterval: 30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000, // 6 months month
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                millisecond: '%H:%M:%S.%L',
                second: '%H:%M:%S',
                minute: '%H:%M',
                hour: '%H:%M',
                day: '%e. %b',
                week: '%e. %b',
                month: '%b',
                year: '%Y'
            }
        },
            yAxis: { // Primary yAxis
                labels: {
                    style: {
                        color: 'blue'
                    }
                },
                gridLineColor: '#197F07',
                gridLineWidth: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Monthly Logons',
                    style: {
                        color: 'blue'
                    }
                }
            },

            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },

            title: {
                text: 'TOTAL MONTHLY LOGONS',
                style: {
                    color: '#333000',
                    fontSize: '14px'
                }
            },

            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y} </b><br>',
                valueDecimals: 2
            },
            series: data


    });
    });
}
```

This is my json file:

```
[{"name":"logon","pointStart":Date.UTC(2011, 1, 1),"pointInterval":30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000,"data":[284697404,268944957,297847827,287150001,277779620,262275285]}]
```

this is the html:

```
<div id="login" style="width:700px; height:300px;"></div>
```

I dont see any errors and no charts either. Any ideas, what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you looked in the console log?  There will be an error: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: highcharts

Comment: @BarbaraLaird, there is no error and no chart.

Comment: If there is no error, than most likely your code isn't getting to this line: var chart = new highcharts({.  How are you calling monthly_web_login?  Are you sure 'monthly_web_login.php' is returning successfully?  Add an alert or a console.log right before your call to highcharts to see if it's getting to that point in the code.

Comment: I can run the php file manually. This is what I have and I dont get any alert on the browser.  $.getJSON('monthly_web_login.php', function(data) {
  alert(data);

Comment: Do you see that GET request failing in your browser's network inspector?

Comment: @NathanHarkenrider, it says get request is OK.

Comment: this is what the browser network inspector shows: [{"name":"logon","pointStart":Date.UTC(2011, 1, 1),"pointInterval":30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000,"data":[284697404,268944957,297847827,287150001,277779620,262275285]}] is this the right format for highcharts?

Comment: @user1471980 That worked in the jsfiddle I posted. If you set a breakpoint on the line that creates the chart is the breakpoint hit?

Comment: @NathanHarkenrider, I tried your example it works. I need to get the file via getjson call to get the file and create the chart. I have many examples of this that are currently in production and working. This is the first time I attempt to create bar chart via $.getJSON('monthly_web_login.php', function(data) { I can run this php script in the command line it works. I have no idea what's really wrong.

Comment: @NathanHarkenrider, it looks like I am getting to the result. One more question, I need data to be on xaxis, it looks it is on yaxis in your example, how would I change that? Thank you so much for your patient help.

Comment: @BarbaraLaird, I got it working but my date data is on yAxis and data on the xAxis. I need date to bon xAxis, any ideas how I would switch it?

Comment: @user1471980 change the chart type from bar to column

Comment: First of all in JSON, you cannot use functions, like Date.UTC(). So this is the first reason of wrong data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't appear that you're associating the chart with a DOM element.

Instead of:

```
var chart = new highcharts({})...
```

Try:

```
var chart = $('#login').highcharts({})...
```

See this jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/pSTcC/) for a working example using your code with minor modifications.

Comment: If you don't want to use the jQuery way of calling it, use  var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({...});

Comment: I tried both, I still dont see any charts on my browser, no error.

Comment: It's marked as an answer, but your comment says otherwise. Does your div have width and height? Can you add console logs at various points to make sure the execution is occurring?